# From which scripture is this Dhyāna mantra of Lord Shiva from?

Tags: shiva, rudra

ध्याये नित्यं महेशं रजतगिरिनिभं चारुचन्द्रावतंसं
रत्नकल्पो   ज्वलान्गम्  परसु मृग वर भितिहस्तं प्रसन्नं
पद्मासिनं  समन्तात स्तुतं अमरगणै :  व्याघ्रकृत्तिं  वसानं
विश्वाद्यं  विश्ववन्द्यं  निखिलभयहरं  पञ्चवक्त्रं  त्रिनेत्रं

This is a popular Dhyāna mantra of Lord Shiva . But to which text does it belong to ? Or who is the person who has composed this Dhyāna Mantra ?

Thanks for reading the question!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This famous **Śiva Dhyana Mantra** is from **Śiva Mahāpurāṇam, Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā, 20.52**

---

**Śiva Dhyāna Mantra**

> ### **ध्यायेन्नित्यं महेशं रजतगिरिनिभं चारुचंद्रा वतंसं रत्नाकल्पोज्ज्वलांगं परशुमृगवराभीतिहस्तं प्रसन्नम् । पद्मासीनं
> समंतात्स्थितममरगणैर्व्याघ्रकृत्तिं वसानं विश्वाद्यं विश्वबीजं
> निखिलभयहरं पंचवक्त्रं त्रिनेत्रम् ॥**
>
> *dhyāyennityaṃ maheśaṃ rajatagirinibhaṃ cārucaṃdrā vataṃsaṃ ratnākalpojjvalāṃgaṃ paraśumṛgavarābhītihastaṃ prasannam | padmāsīnaṃ
> samaṃtātsthitamamaragaṇairvyāghrakṛttiṃ vasānaṃ viśvādyaṃ viśvabījaṃ
> nikhilabhayaharaṃ paṃcavaktraṃ trinetram ||*
>
> **~ Śivapurāṇam, Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā, 20.52**
>
> He shall meditate on Śiva always in the following way:— He is like a
> silver mountain. He wears the beautiful moon, on his forehead. His
> limbs are resplendent with ornaments of gems. He holds the axe, the
> deer, the Mudrā of boon and the Mudrā of freedom from fear in His four
> hands. He is joyful. He is seated in the lotus pose. The assembled
> Devas stand around Him and offer prayers. He wears the hide of the
> tiger. He is the primordial Being, the seed of the universe. He
> dispels all fears. He is the three-eyed lord with five faces.

[image]

Comment: @অনু Why do you edited my answer ? Why do you deleted the Hindi translation ?

Comment: This website is dedicated to sharing Hindu religious content  across the linguistic divide & English had been unanimously chosen as the common language of interaction during the time of the cite's creation. Since you have already given the English translation of the Sanskrit verses, providing Hindi translation of the same was irrelevant. However, if you remain unsatisfied with the explanation, you may contact the moderators in this regard.

Comment: @অনু  But why will you edit someone's answer without his permission ? You should talk me first about your problem.

Comment: Please calm down. Since you are new to this cite, you may not know but users with higher reputation have the priviledge to edit the posts (both questions & answers) of others in this cite with the aim of improving it's quality. As you don't have enough reputation, the cite didn't provide you the option to allow you to choose whether you can accept edits made by others in your posts in the final draft or not. The cite notifies it to you & gives you that option once you have a certain amount of reputation. However, if you feel outraged, I apologize to you for it.

Comment: @অনু  Ok... brother, I wasn't aware of this . I am new in this site and till learning about this site's technique. Don't mind. Śiva Śivā !